# How to make Packet sniffer in java?

Tags: java, packet, libpcap, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I am trying to make a packet sniffer in java.

My environment is Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

The first thing I found from internet recommends install Jpcap,

But I could not find any Jpcap installation files for Ubuntu 64bit.

After that I was trying to install libpcap.

I have downloaded source file from http://www.tcpdump.org .

However, when I commands "./configure", it shows me errors like below.

```
 error: Your operating system's lex is insufficient to compile
 libpcap.  flex is a lex replacement that has many advantages, including
 being able to compile libpcap.
```

it sounds like I have to install flex which I really do not want to.

So is there any way to install this or replacement of this which

library for java, so I can use classes in eclipse?

Thanks for reading and answers.

And can I get some java sample codes for capturing packets?

Comment: why not install flex? `build-essential` might include it i think

Comment: Why don't you just `apt-get install libpcap`?

Comment: @fge I already tried that one. But it displays Unable to locate package libpcap.

Comment: @KarthikT For test, I can install flex. But for realize, I can not install. this program will run on Server. If I want to install flex additionally it take many times and steps. That is why I do not want to use extra things.

Comment: libpcap _is_ available for Ubuntu. Its name may not be libpcap. Just `apt-cache search pcap` and pick the right choice.

Comment: @fge Maybe name is OK. when I did that command I can get libpcap0.8. But anyway, it stil needs flex. I guess maybe flex is very necessary factor of libpcap. Maybe I should install flex :-(